# How do I access information about a cascading dynamic prompt via Crystal Report API?

Tags: .net, api, crystal-reports

I am using the CR 2008 RAS API (but could also use an older API if needed). Any idea how to access information about the settings for dynamic prompts in a report?

I can access the PromptField objects with

```
dataDefController.ParameterFieldController.
    GetPromptParameterFields(new PropertyBagClass());
```

but can't seem to find any options for its dynamic prompt settings (such as fields used to fill the default values, cascading prompt settings, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Here are two links that are helpful for the RAS API.

API reference:
http://help.sap.com/businessobject/product_guides/boexir31/en/rassdk_net_apiRef_12_en.chm

Dev Guide:
http://help.sap.com/businessobject/product_guides/boexir31/en/rassdk_net_dg_12_en.chm

Unfortunately they don't seem to completely answer your question, but maybe they'll help.